# After + verb+ing or after + having + past participle?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, difference, tense, sentence-structure

What are the differences between the two following sentences?

1. She recovered well after stopping the pills.
2. She recovered well after having stopped the pills?

Comment: Although the use of the past perfect in (2) seems logical, there is no need for it because the meaning is clear from (1). However, native speakers would probably say _She recovered well after she stopped taking the pills_.

Comment: The first sentence is definitely fine.
The using of past perfect in the second sentence isn’t pertinent to me.